# ¿Cómo ordenar la posicion de una lista de acuerdo a otra lista Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo esta lista: (1) `[6, 7, 8, 9]`

y tengo esta otra lista: (2)  `[6,8]`

Mediante un bucle, quiero generar otra lista de acuerdo al orden   de la original y donde no haya elementos teniendo en cuenta la lista No **2** poner **0**

**Quedaría asi: [6,0,8,0]**

Gracias a quien me logre ayudar con la solución.

Comment: Hola. No sobra que consultes [ask] y luego entres a [edit] tu pregunta y muestres lo que has intentado. Recuerda que debes tratar de ofrecer un [mcve]

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no demuestra ningún esfuerzo.

Answer (score 3):

```
lista1 = [6, 7, 8, 9] 
lista2 = [6,8]
lista3 = []
for elem in lista1:
  if elem in lista2:
    lista3.insert(lista1.index(elem),elem)
  else:
    lista3.insert(lista1.index(elem),0)
print(lista3)
```

Comment: Felicitaciones.